# Can I use a mosfet as a switch to power arduino?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, timer, 555, mosfet-driver

I have a project in which I intend to use a NE555 timer to turn the arduino on/off on specific intervals.
I don't want to use the ne555 output directly because of the current limitations of the chip.
I was wondering if I can connect the timer output to a P-channel Mosfet gate and get my output from its drain?

Here is the schematics.The resistor is supposed to be arduino board.
[image]

Since there is no way to really simulate this I wanted to be sure before I assemble the circuit so I appreciate if you could point out any possible problems.

Comment: Lots of ways to simulate it . Why 555?  Why 50 Ohms?  Why not sleep timer?

Comment: The 555 adds no value at all, learn to use the Arduino Sleep modes.

Comment: "*I don't want to use the ne555 output directly because of the current limitations of the chip.*", What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: This is not a good circuit. The Vgs(th) of the FET is too large. Find one that has a guaranteed low Rds(on) specified at V(gs) of 4.5V or lower. Note that the supply for the 555 should be the same voltage as the FET is switching. Or the 555 could be a bit higher. That would work, too. There should probably also be a pull-up resistor from gate to source. The 50 Ohm resistor serves no purpose that I can see. Unless it is meant to represent the Arduino load current, in which case, OK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work, but you don't need the 50Ω resistor as it will only waste power.

The second thing is you may not need to use this circuit at all! Why? because you can get an [arudino to use very little current in a sleep mode](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/reducing-arduino-power-consumption), like 10uA of current. The supply current is at least 3mA for an NE555 and the 555 timer needs to be operating all of the time. The aruidno only needs 10uA to sleep so a 555 timer wastes 300x more current.

And you can simulate circuits like this:
 (you can click on edit below the image and then click simulate) 
I have simulated the load as 10Ω, which would be a peak load of 500mA for an arudino.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH6a6j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It would be a lot better to get a MOSFET with a lower Vgs(th). I would choose one with an Rds(on) that is low and is specified at Vgs = -4.5V or lower. Such are readily available.

Comment: I just showed that example for the sake of simulation, that a circuit of that nature can be simulated. The OP can pick the FET, I'm not sure what's available in CircuitLab and I'm not about to look through the list

Comment: Sure. I know. Consider my comment to be directed at those who find this answer in the future and don't know any better.

Answer (score 0):

In general yes, but the circuit as you have shown will probably run into trouble with that particular mosfet unless you do some weird business with your 555.

The mosfet has a threshold voltage minimum of -4V. Rule of thumb-wise, this means that -5V (relative to your +5V rail, so 0V) on the gate will not be nearly enough to turn it on fully, so you'll have to do one of the following:

- Have your 555 output swing from +5V to about -3V to -5V. You don't want to do this. Too complicated.
- Pick a new MOSFET that has a threshold voltage closer to, say, 1.5V. May I suggest something like the [MCH3333A](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MCH3333A-D.PDF) from On Semi? For an arduino you don't need more than maybe 500mA continuous current, and even that has plenty of margin.

Also, I would suggest something similar to the following drive circuit (mainly the part about using pin 7):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcfqcC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Pin 7 is the open-collector output and will allow you to fully turn off the MOSFET. Unless you do something like run your 555 at like 9V, the Pin 3 output may not quite reach 5V and could possibly not fully shut off the MOSFET. This design will bring your Vgs to at least -4.3V when turned on and "relax" your Vgs to 0V when turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use MOSFET for this and you already got some answers how to do it properly.

What I'd like to suggest though, is use "Power-down" sleep mode (0.1 uA!) of your Arduino and wake it up using interrupt from external timer chip, like these: [TPL5111](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpl5111.pdf) (0.04 uA!), [TPL5110-Q1](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpl5110-q1.pdf), [TPL5010-Q1](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpl5010-q1.pdf) etc. You will save much more power doing it this way.

Here is an example how to use this method with [RV8523 RTC chip](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/379229/).